# Unable to Handle SocketException

Tags: flutter, dart

I've internet turned off my phone to trigger a `SocketException` error. I make my api call and at the top of the stack the error can be seen on my debugger just before the `await` call. I want to handle this error at the UI layer. And at the bottom of my call stack I see the method `getData` . My understanding is: I can wrap this in a try/catch and handle the exception. But I can't seem to grab the error.. Here is the method:

```
Future<String> getData(String query) async {
    try {
      List<Suburb> suburbs = await model.getSuburbs('au', query);

      if (suburbs.length == 1) {
        suburbCode = suburbs[0].code;
        isButtonDisabled = false;
        return suburbs[0].name;
      }
      return showDialog<String>(
          barrierDismissible: false,
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => SimpleDialog(
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                title: Text('Please choose your Suburb:'),
                children: suburbs
                    .map((suburb) => SimpleDialogOption(
                        child: Text(suburb.name),
                        onPressed: () {
                          suburbCode = suburb.code;
                          isButtonDisabled = false;

                          Navigator.of(context).pop(suburb.name);
                        }))
                    .toList(),
              ));
    } on SocketException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

The line `List<Suburb> suburbs = await model.getSuburbs('au', query);` is where I make the api call and where the debugger points to. But I can't seem to 'get in to the catch block'

Comment: `on SocketException catch (e) {` should work. Try to add this block within getSuburbs() and check.  In one of my code, I catch socket exception where the API call is made [so inside `getSuburbs()`] in your context) and throw a generic exception (via enum) from the caller [i.e.`getData()`]

Comment: maybe I should add that the method is a future for a FutureBuilder. But I don't think that makes any difference

Comment: thanks..getSuburbs() needed an await.

Comment: Cool. Let me add it as an answer so that others would be benefitted as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The try-catch block will need at the Http post/get call as well. So, just catch the socket exception in `getSuburbs()`, do the needful and throw a general exception from there, if required. Something like below would work :

```
Future<string> getSuburbs(string country, string query){
    try {
        http.Response response =
            await http.post(.........
      } on SocketException catch (e) {
        print(e);
        throw Error.noNetworkConnection;
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
        throw Error.unknown;
      }
}
```